# EhCache on RDBMS and spill/restore to/from disk when RDBMS is down

Tags: caching, ehcache, distributed-caching

I'm using EhCache. I want to provide a caching layer on top of an existing RDBMS. However, in case the database server is down, I want EhCache to write to a particular location on disk. Later when the database server is up, I want the data on the disk to be synched to the database.

> Assume there is only one instance of EhCache, i.e. it's not clustered.

Is that possible to do using EhCache? If so, what all do I need to do?

Answer (score 0):

Using a wise `CacheLoaderWriter`, that should be possible. You just need the writer to have a built in failover that will right to disk.

Of course, your use-case is pretty specific so there's nothing in Ehcache supporting it off-the-shelf.